# Select and Edit all buttons in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button

The routine below allows the user to toggle where they have completed/not completed the required entry. The button text changes to Complete/Incomplete and the adjacent cell goes green/red using simple conditional formatting on the 0 or 1 value. Works fine for updating a single line.

The number of data entry rows will vary for each user (say 10 to 100) and I am trying to find a way of selecting and then changing all the buttons in the sheet to "Complete" and updating the adjacent cell to 0 or 1 in one go, should the user want to do that.

Each row is a data entry line and each cell in Column B has a button, and a 0/1 in adjacent cell in Column C.

```
Sub complete()
'Complete / Incomplete Buttton and Flag

Dim buttontext As String

buttontext = Application.Caller
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Select
ActiveCell.Select

If ActiveSheet.Buttons(buttontext).Caption = "Mark as Incomplete" Then
    ActiveSheet.Buttons(buttontext).Caption = "Mark as Complete"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1

    Else
    ActiveSheet.Buttons(buttontext).Caption = "Mark as Incomplete"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0

End If

End Sub
```

Following code works:

```
Sub MarkAllComplete()
Dim btn As Button
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
btn.Caption = "Mark as Complete"
Cells(btn.TopLeftCell.Row, btn.TopLeftCell.Column + 1) = 0
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So is there data, say A1:A100 and then 100 buttons in B1:B100?

Comment: Yes - there is data on each line. Use Col A for current purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Use this concept:

```
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
    Debug.Print btn.Name, btn.TopLeftCell.Column, btn.TopLeftCell.Row
Next
```

Comment: Thanks - that did it `Sub MarkAllComplete()
Dim btn As Button
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
btn.Caption = "Mark as Complete"
Cells(btn.TopLeftCell.Row, btn.TopLeftCell.Column + 1) = 0
Next
End Sub`