# How to search a worksheet for existing command buttons?

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning, I am looking for a VBA code that will search an excel sheet for existing command buttons and if they were not found it would add them. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()

Dim objBtn As OLEObject, r As Range
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("C11:I21")
        If cell.Value = "button name" Then found = True
        Next cell

        If Not found Then
            Set objBtn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, _
                 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=90, Height:=30)

                objBtn.Object.Caption = "button caption"


        End If

End Sub
```

The problem is I am looking inside cells and buttons are practically not, they are kind of above cells. So how do I look for them? One photo to show how a command button look like:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555034/select-and-edit-all-buttons-in-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the Oleobjects-collection and you could make a list of excisting buttons in your sheet and then act if some are missing;

```
Sub test()
Dim x As OLEObject, s As String, YourButtons() As Variant, btn As Variant, objBtn As OLEObject
YourButtons = Array("CommandButton1", "CommandButton5", "CommandButton3", "CommandButton4")
With Sheet1
    For Each x In .OLEObjects
        If TypeName(x.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            s = s & "|" & x.Name
    End If
    Next
    For Each btn In YourButtons
        If InStr(1, s, btn, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
             Set objBtn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, _
                 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=90, Height:=30)
                objBtn.Object.Caption = "button caption"
        End If
    Next btn
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Marked as answer because the comment showed me I can loop through OLEObject. Thanks.